# Split and change first character of a word to uppercase in Python

Tags: python, string, loops, uppercase

I have a list:

```
s = ['SMITH', 'JONES', 'Paul']
```

I need only the fist letter of each element to be uppercase and all the elements to be connected by an underscore:

```
s = ['Smith_Jones_Paul']
```

I have a number of those and want to make a loop to change all of them. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) string method on each word in the list and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings together with an underscore:

```
>>> '_'.join(x.capitalize() for x in s)
'Smith_Jones_Paul'
```

In summary...

- `capitalize` puts a string's first character to uppercase and the subsequent characters to lowercase.
- `(x.capitalize() for x in s)` applies the `capitalize` to each string in your list `s`.
- `join` takes a list (or other iterable) of strings and joins the strings together with a delimiter (in this case an underscore).

N.B. It's worth noting that passing a list to `join` is more efficient than giving it the generator expression shown above:

```
>>> %timeit '_'.join([x.capitalize() for x in s]) # list
1000000 loops, best of 3: 866 ns per loop

>>> %timeit '_'.join(x.capitalize() for x in s) # generator
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 us per loop
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you, I'll add that point to the answer.

Comment: unfortunately if I print I get 'smith jones paul'

Comment: @blackforest Then you're doing something wrong, this answer works.

Comment: you are right, just checked and outside my loop works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doing the "manual" work is (just a little) faster:

```
>>> "_".join([x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in s])
'Smith_Jones_Paul'
```

Actually a bit confused with the benchmark:

```
>>> %timeit '_'.join([x.capitalize() for x in s])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 817 ns per loop

>>> %timeit '_'.join([x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in s])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 796 ns per loop
```

The variation is really high in this case. But when I do a simple for loop for this case:

```
z = ["aasdfasdfasdfsadfa", "aasdfasdfasdfsadfa", "aasdfasdfasdfsadfa", 
     "aasdfasdfasdfsadfa", "aasdfasdfasdfsadfb"] * 10

for i in range(1000000): 
    a = [x[0] + x[1:] for x in z]

for i in range(1000000):
    b = [x.capitalize() for x in z]
```

There is a difference of 9 vs 16 seconds!